# Rationale behind the difference of global and local variable initialization with constexpr

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr int func() { return 42; }
```

Now, if I define a global variable initialized with `func()`, then it is guaranteed that `func()` will be compile-time evaluated, as the variable need to be static initialized:

```
int a = func(); // here, func() will be compile-time evaluated
                // note that a is NOT constexpr
```

But, if I initialize a local variable in a function, then it isn't guaranteed that `func()` will be compile-time evaluated:

```
int foo() {
    int b = func(); // no guarantee that func() will be compile-time evaluated
    return b;
}
```

I understand, that if I use `constexpr int b = func();`, then it will be compile-time evaluated. But, this makes `b` `const`. What if I want to modify `b` afterwards?

Why is there the difference between these two cases?

Comment: "Why is there the difference between these two cases?" Because local variables are created at run-time?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: global variables are created at run-time too, just at the beginning of program execution

Comment: "it is guaranteed that `func()` will be compile-time evaluated" - I guess this is wrong, could you quote the Standard, please?

Comment: @Evg: "Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity."  http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#2 So this should mean that `func()` must be evaluated compile-time during initializing `a`.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see a requirement that *constant initialization* must happen at compile-time.

Comment: @Evg: hmm. Maybe that's allowed to do it run-time, indeed. I just based my assumption on that compilers put static initialized objects into the executable itself (so they evaluate initialization at compile-time). Actually, maybe your comment is the answer to my question.

Comment: Compilers will initialize global variables at compile time when they can, but your `int a = func();` works just fine even if `func` is not `constexper`.  It's no different than calling a constructor for a global string variable.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: the generated code differs. If it is `constexpr`, then `a` will be initialized to 42 compile-time (i.e., `a` is initialized to 42 in the exe). If it is not `constexpr`, then there will be a function call at run-time (even in release builds, and interestingly, even if `func` is `inline` - tested with gcc).

Comment: @geza Yeah, but if `func()` is a constant when initializing `a`, why shouldn't it be one when initializing `b`?  I guess I'm missing why you thing the two should behave differently.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I don't think two should behave differently. Quite the contrary, I think they should behave the same. And looking at the standard, and the generated assembly code, they do behave differently. `a` initialized compile-time, while `b` involves a function call (which of course will be optimized away for this simple case in release builds, but for complex cases, it won't).

Comment: Which compiler are you looking at?  I put your code on godbolt.org.  gcc and clang used constants for both, while msvc had function calls for both.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: clang 7.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Once you put b on the stack you can modify it unless you used `int b const = foo ();`. There would be no benefit to marking such a function as `constexpr` over `const`. For most purposes on modern CPUs, constexpr is a method to decrease your boot time, which matters more for smartphones with slower processors and memory.

For embedded systems, we use constexpr to put stuff into ROM easier. The alternative method makes a script that prints out the C/C++ code for you, but that is an extra step. You don't think about this on a PC/Server/Smartphone because you use `new` to create dynamic memory, but you can't do that on most embedded systems (but that has changed with more RAM and ROM on microcontrollers), but with embedded systems you have different types of memory and you need to place stuff either in RAM or ROM. This is where context is a godsend, and also in high-performance computing, but there is no difference to the compiler between `const int foo () { return 420; }` and `constexpr foo () { return 420; }`, they both get replaced with a single move instruction without running the O2 optimizer.

My favorite use of constexpr for embedded systems so far is to ensure that there is only one copy of a Remote Procedure Call (RPC) header in ROM. The alternative method is to use strings, which may or may not end up getting duplicated. constexpr allows you can use a variadic template to create arrays of types other than int, which has historically been very tedious requiring multiple steps.

The Golden rule of C++ optimizations is don't try to trick the compiler with some faster way someone else taught you that works great 15 years ago. Instead, you should instruct the compiler what you want it to do, turn O2 optimizations on, and the optimizing compiler will ditch your code and replace it with a version optimized for that CPU **#LikeABoss**. Don't be like me and use pointer arithmetic to engineer a massive sockets API and waste hundreds of hours hand-optimizing code only to the O2 optimizer come and delete all your pretty sometimes better-optimized code you were so proud of.